# How to hide specific table columns on button click using jquery?

Tags: jquery

So here is my code:

```
      <div>
          <a class="button" data-value="lt">lt</a>
      </div> 
     <div>
          <a class="button" data-value="en">en</a>
      </div>
```

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th class="lt">Code lt</th>
            <th style="display:none;" class="en">Code en</th>
            <th class="lt">Value lt</th>
            <th style="display:none;" class="en">Value en</th>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td class="lt">code1_lt</td>
                <td style="display:none;" class="en">code2_en</td>
                <td class="lt">value1_lt</td>
                <td style="display:none;" class="lt">value2_en</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

So for example when i click on first button i want to hide columns with en (so its the 3rd and 5th ones)
And do same with other button to hide lt columns

Nvm fixed it myself. Thanks all who helped
Here is how i did it:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.button', function(e) {
      var value = jQuery(this).attr('data-value');

      if(value == 'lt')
      {
          jQuery('.lt').show();
          jQuery('.en').hide();
      }

      if(value == 'en')
      {
          jQuery('.en').show();
          jQuery('.lt').hide();
      }


  });
```

Comment: en and lt are PHP code. so it will render something different on the browser. So distinguish based on that is impossible. Please share the rendered HTML in the browser so that a proper solution can give. BTW what you tried so far? Please add your effort in your question

Comment: If you know the langs beforehand as per your php code, why don't you set a specific class and just hide it ? `$(".lang_en").hide();`.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this  , this will hide column no 2

```
  $('#btnid').click(function() {
    $('td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').hide();
  })
```

or you can do this assing calss .en and .lt to columns and hide it

```
      $('#btnlt').click(function() {
        $('.lt').hide();
      })

      $('#btnen').click(function() {
        $('.en').hide();
      })

  <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th class='lt'>Code lt</th>
            <th class='en'>Code en</th>
            <th class='lt'>Value lt</th>
            <th class='en'>Value en</th>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
                <td class='lt'><?php echo $row->code_lt; ?></td>
                <td class='en'><?php echo $row->code_en; ?></td>
                <td class='lt'><?php echo $row->value_lt; ?></td>
                <td class='en'><?php echo $row->value_en; ?></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class` with `index` to hide column.

```js
$(".button").on("click", function() {
 $('td').removeClass('ab');
 $('th').removeClass('ab');
  var btn = $(this).val();
  $('table tr th').each(function(index, element) {
    var str = $(this).text();

    if (str.indexOf(btn) !== -1) {
      $(this).addClass('ab');
      $("td:nth-child(" + index + ")").addClass('ab');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.ab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type='button' value="lt" class="button" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type='button' value='en' class="button" />
</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Code lt</th>
    <th>Code en</th>
    <th>Value lt</th>
    <th>Value en</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```